# Getting 500 on query

Tags: php, mysql

```
$result = $db->execute("
INSERT INTO arrowchat_chatroom_rooms (author_id, name, description, welcome_message, image, type,password, length, max_users, session_time, limit_message_num, limit_seconds_num) 
VALUES ('" . $db->escape_string($userid) . "', 
'" . $_POST["add_chatroom_name"] . "',
'" . $_POST["add_chatroom_desc"] . "', 
'" . $_POST["add_chatroom_welcome_msg" . "', 
'" . $db->escape_string($icon_filename) ."', 
'". $_POST["add_chatroom_type"] . "', 
'" . $_POST["add_chatroom_password"] . "', 
'" . $_POST["add_chatroom_length"] . "', 
'" . $_POST["chatroom_max_users"] . "', 
'" . time() . "', 
'" . $_POST["limit_message_num"] . "', 
'" . *_POST["limit_seconds_num"] . "')"
);
```

return http 500 x_x

Comment: could be the last item *_POST["limit_seconds_num"] note the * not a $

Comment: Joke mode on: You're running the newest version of PHP which now has build-in protection against SQL-injection.

Comment: If you formatted things a bit neater it would be easier to pick out problems. One thing I noticed is you've got `*_POST["limit_seconds_num"]` near the end and that should probably be `$_POST["limit_seconds_num"]`.

Comment: 1) don't EVER put raw `POST` data into `MySQL` without sanitizing it!!  2) I'd be willing to be there's a problem with one of your `$_POST` variables being either it's not set, or it's the wrong data type..  Use this at the top of your page `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: (fixed last "$" post item still not working) @Zak readed up. Btw. i always read the manual lol

Comment: code is postegres like functions get_var, var_check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing the closing `]` for

```
$_POST["add_chatroom_welcome_msg"
```

and * in the start of

```
*_POST["limit_seconds_num"]
```

in your query, and that is the most probable cause of your `500` error try enabling the `display_errors = On` from the `php.ini`

Comment: Fixed 500. sample code contains functions get_var, check_var [...] IS THIS Postegres ?